# Error loading the program after use FileDialog in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Write a program in QT on C++ using QML. Added to QML a choice of folders (FileDialog). After opening the FileDialog window breaks the program. Found out that the program breaks at the location of the object is deleted, delete ptc in c++ code. I wonder what if FileDialog is not used, then everything works as it should. Weird.

Run QML inside of the GUI object:

```
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("GUI", this);
QQmlComponent *component = new QQmlComponent(&engine,QUrl("ui.qml"));
mainview = component->create();
```

Create a FileDialog within ui.qml in ApplicationWinow

```
FileDialog {
    id: fileDialog
    property int number
    title: "Выбор дирректории"
    folder: shortcuts.home
    modality : Qt.WindowModal
    onAccepted: {
        switch (number) {
        case 0: secondPage.setDir(fileUrl.toString().replace("file:///", "")); break;
        case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4: case 5: case 6:
            firstPage.setDir(fileUrl,number); break;
        default: break;
        }
    }
}
```

The place of crash of the prog:

```
bool raschet::R1()
{
    float PolPr = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        QList<float>* ptcA1;
        QString put = getData(1,0,0,0,(i/2 +2 ) % 3,i%2);
        if (!put.count())
            return false;
        while (!FormatPTC(&ptcA1, put, i % 2, (i/2 +2 ) % 3, 0, 0, -10, 10, 0.01))
            zapuskRasch(1, 20, 20, -10, -10, 0.01, 1, 0, 0, put, puts1);
        for (int j = 1; j <=3; j++)
        {
            poiskProval(ptcA1[0],ptcA1[j],&(PolPr = 0));
            //saveXLS(j-1,i+6,PolPr*60,sheet);
        }
        delete ptcA1; //!!!!!
    }
    return true; 
}
```

P.S. Do not allocate memory for ptcA1, because it is allocated inside the function FormatPTC

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand why ptcA1 created like a pointer

Comment: The problems seems to be unrelated with `FileDialog`. Please try to localise your problem by creating a [mcve]. Providing us the definition of `FormatPTC` may be relevant too.

Comment: I already figured out the problem. Had to delete this:  delete[] ptcA1
Thanks.

Comment: I wonder how does `FileDialog` relates to the issue? Or `QML` at all. As for the problem - create `ptcA1` on the stack and so it will be deleted automatically after the function ends.

Comment: When are you assigning `ptcA1`?  Inside `FormatPTC` ?  Do you know that you're passing in a `QList<float> * *` ( pointer to a pointer to a QList<float>).  `FormatPTC` will need to assign to the dereference of that pointer.  I'd start by assigning `ptcA1` initally like `QList<float>* ptcA1 = nullptr;`

Comment: @Andrey Please consider clarifying your question and writing an answer yourself as it could be useful for other users with the same problem.